# Python 2.7 __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I've got these classes.
`Person` is the parent class and `Student` is the child class:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, avr, name):
        self.avr = avr
        super(Student, self).__init__(self, name)
```

I get this error when I try to make an instance of `Student`:

```
__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you creating an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using super, you don't pass `self` to the target method.  It is passed implicitly.

```
super(Student, self).__init__(name)
```

That's 2 arguments total (self, name).  When you passed `self`, that was 3 total (self, self, name).

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
super(Student, self).__init__(name)
```

in which self has been passed to **init** method,so you don't need to write it out again in `__init__` method.
But if you use

```
super(Student, Student).__init__(self, name)
```

or

```
super(Student, self.__class__).__init__(self, name)
```

you have to write down self in `__init__` method.

Comment: `super(Student, Student)` is **wrong** and `super(Student, self.__class__)` is even more **wrong**.